# How to host a Proxy Server on Windows Server?

Tags: proxy, http, windows-server

I would like to host a http/https proxy server on my windows server. I want to connect to that proxy server (with authorization) from another computer, so my application uses the IP adress of this windows server.

There are thousands of guides out there, how to connect to a proxy server, but I haven't found a single one, how to actually **host** one. I read about some options you have on linux, however i have a windows server operation system. I am thankful for every answers which help me out. Do I need special software to host one? If yes, which one?

Comment: Well, yes, a proxy server is software just like anything else.  Windows Server comes with IIS which _can_ act as a reverse proxy.  Otherwise you would need to install and configure one of the numerous other products that run on Windows Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if Microsoft have a product (it seems likely) but my first choice might be [Squid](https://www.google.com/search?q=squid+proxy+windows)

Having said that, last time I needed a dedicated low-throughput single-purpose proxy, I wrote one in Go. Obviously this is probably more work that you want but configuring a sophisticated proxy may not be your idea of fun either.

Comment: thanks, squid seems to do exactly what I need!